# Module Amnesia with Apache Beam DirectRunner option multi_processing

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm using the multi_processing pipeline option with Apache Beam's DirectRunner and my Python modules aren't being recognized. The multi_processing works great on any function that doesn't require an imported library.

I've tried both a global and non-rooted python venv, I've tried importing the module within the relevant ParDo (although I've since seen that fail in another thread), I've also tried importing the pipeline process into a main file and running it in the venv with the appropriate packages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.